# How to bind two events at the same time using jPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jplayer

I'm trying to attach two event handlers at the same time. Here is an example:

```
$("#jpId").bind($.jPlayer.event.loadeddata, function(event){});

$("#jpId").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event){});
```

I don't know how but like this:

```
$("#jpId").bind($.jPlayer.event.loadeddata || $.jPlayer.event.play, function(event){});
```

I want to use this two events at same time.

Comment: Try : `.bind("loadeddata play", pCallback)`

Comment: Not working @Lauromine . Please see updated......

Comment: Hay someone help me plz.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below if you want to use anonymous function:

```
$("#jpId").bind(
   $.jPlayer.event.loadeddata + ' ' + $.jPlayer.event.play,
   function(event){
      // ... skipped ...
   }
);
```